# Colocar datos numéricos sobre gráficos en Power BI utilizando base de datos de casetas(Logística) en Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi

Le cargue al Power BI un Excel con una de datos de caseta tomadas(peajes) de nuestros vehículos.

Quisiera si alguien me pudiera orientar a como colocarle que el valor que se esta sumando aparezca visible sobre cada columna de datos. Le coloque una flecha roja en donde quisiera que aparezca el numero que corresponde por ejempo "$1000.00"

[image: BASE DE DATOS DE CASETAS-Ejemplo para colocar información-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar la cantidad por barra de la gráfica haces lo siguiente.

1. Selecciona tu `Gráfico` para abrir la barra lateral derecha y ver sus características.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. En el apartado visualizaciones da click en `"dar formato a objeto visual"`.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Busca la pestaña o apartado `"Etiquetas de datos"` y la habilitas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. En el apartado `serie le das en "todas"` y `opciones "Vertical"` o como te convenga, también te ahí puedes darle mas formato a otras cosas como fuente, etc. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Quedara así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dime si te funciono.

Comment: Si me funciono, gracias por el dato, ya pude visualizar la información. Con este avance ya se me abre un hilo de muchas mas preguntas sobre la misma base. Es que tengo otra base donde tengo la relación de que TAG pertenece a que unidad y que unidad pertenece a que sucursal, y que unidad(vehículo) esta asignada a que chofer. ahora quiero ver como puede asignar "unidades" a los TAGS para que el cálculo se tome por TAG pero que visualice el "económico" de la unidad. Se es que es mucho mas avanzado de mi conocimiento actual.

Comment: Puedes generar una nueva pregunta agregando mas detalle del problema, recuerda adjuntar el intento que haz realizado para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y puedas obtener una buena respuesta.